# Meteor: Handling Facebook Realtime API Requests via Callback-Url with iron-router

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm trying to use the Facebook Realtime API with a Meteor app. Basically you can subscribe to an object like page or user and get update notifications so that no polling is needed (publish/subscribe pattern).

So I need to setup a callback URL and send a post request with my callbackurl, the object & fields that I want to subscribe and a verify string. A FB server is sending a get request with my verify string and a random string (challenge) and the Meteor server has to respond to this with the challenge string. (If you're interested in details you can read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/subscriptions/)).

I'm getting the following error serverside:

> [ec2-11-11-1-123.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] Exception while invoking method 'createSubscription' Error: error while subscribing to object page - failed [400] {"error":{"message":"(#2200) callback
>   verification failed: Operation timed out after 6000 milliseconds with
>   0 bytes received","type":"OAuthException","code":2200}}
>       at subscription (packages/fbuilder/lib/server/methods.js:20)
>       at Meteor.methods.createSubscription (packages/fbuilder/lib/server/methods.js:110)
>       at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1487)
>       at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:643
>       at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
>       at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:642
>       at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
>       at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:641)
>       at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:541

So i guess something is wrong with the router part listening to the given URL...

```
Router.map(function () {

// Callback URL of the server for verification and receiving data via FB Realtime API
this.route('fbCallbackURL', {
    path: Meteor.settings.fbCallbackPath,
    where: 'server',
    action: function() {

        var req = this.request;
        var res = this.response;

        switch(req.method){
          "GET" :
                  var hub = req.hub;
                  console.log("got something ...........");

                  if(hub && hub.verify_token === Meteor.settings.fbVerifyString
                         && hub.mode==='subscribe' && hub.challenge){

                    res.writeHead(200);
                    res.end({hub: {challenge: hub.challenge}});
                  }
                  else{
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.end("");
                  }

                  break;


          "POST":
                  console.log("todo");
/*
                  The HTTP request will contain an X-Hub-Signature header which contains the SHA1 signature of the request payload,
                  using the app secret as the key, and prefixed with sha1=. Your callback endpoint can verify this signature
                  to validate the integrity and origin of the payload.*/

                  break;

          default: res.writeHead(404);
      }

    }
})
});
```

Here's the code where I create the subscription:

```
function subscription(object,fields,active){

if(object){
  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+Meteor.settings.fbAppId+'/subscriptions',
  res,
  params = {
                  access_token : Meteor.settings.fbAppId + '|' + Meteor.settings.fbAppSecret,
                  callback_url : Meteor.settings.fbAppURL+""+Meteor.settings.fbCallbackPath,
                  object : object,
                  verify_token : Meteor.settings.fbVerifyString,
                  fields : fields
  };

  try {
      res = HTTP.post(url , { params: params } );

  } catch (err) {
    throw _.extend(
      new Error("error while subscribing to object " + object + " - " + err.message + "   ",{response: err.response}));
  }

  return res;


}
  else
        new Error("subscription for invalid object requested!");

};
```

So I'm calling this function via a method on the server: (just for testing)

```
Meteor.methods({

createSubscription: function() {
    return subscription("page","name",true);
}

});
```

Any ideas or suggestions? :(

Thanks in advance!